# HD 1080p .mkv videos don't play smooth. Is it a CPU, GPU, player or OS issue?

Tags: vlc-media-player, gpu, cpu-usage, high-definition, video-playback

I have some .mkv 1080p videos but VLC can't play them smoothly.

If I open the Task Manager, I can see that CPU is at 100%, because VLC uses as much as it can (95% or more).

Then, I wonder

- Is it a CPU problem, because it's slow?
- Is it a GPU problem because it isn't so good, so the CPU must do all work?
- Is it a player problem, because it's a VLC bug, or it doesn't use the right codec, or doesn't support hardware acceleration?
- Is it a OS problem, because XP it's too old?

I have:

- CPU: DualCore AMD Athlon 64 X2, 2200 MHz (11 x 200) 4200+
- GPU: nVIDIA nForce 6100-430
- Player: VLC v2.0.5
- OS: Windows XP SP3

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, I wouldn't have the below answer without it!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VLC uses the CPU heavily, you can find other players that utilize the GPU better.  Daum PotPlayer, SMPlayer,  Gom Player.  [LifeHacker Link](http://lifehacker.com/5822672/the-best-video-player-for-windows)

Comment: PotPlayer uses 100% CPU too, but it plays the video smoothly, thanks

Comment: VLC can offload decoding to the GPU where supported by drivers and video card - http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding.  If your video is slow, you probably need to find video acceleration drivers for your Video card (or get a new one if your card does not have GPU acceleration)

Comment: Tried the first one - Daum PotPlayer and works amazing! Thanks.
Still have to check if it is eating 100% cpu as first comments but still all popular players like vlc, realplayer and many failed to play my youtube downloaded mkv file but this one worked flawless!! Thanks once again :)

Comment: cpu keeps jumping between 28 to 44 percent. I can always take it considering the quality it gives.

Answer (score 2):

Your GPU doesn't support accelerated HD decoding. More recent GPUs can handle HD decoding and are much more efficient at this than CPUs.

Comment: Thanks, I will take it on account when I update my computer. But meanwhile, I prefer Ryan E's answer, it's cheaper :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option relating to changing VLC settings is that you can also try to disable or enable hardware decoding. Enabling it worked for me: Preferences -> Under Show Settings, click 'All' -> Input/Codecs -> Video Codecs -> FFmpeg -> Search for the Hardware decoding checkbox and try checking/unchecking it.

More information related to this issue can be found at:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/fix-for-vlc-skipping-and-lagging-playing-high-def-video-files

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I saw the solution on another site and it worked for me. The 1080p file actually played fine in windows media player, so I knew it wasn't my computer. The solution is to change the file cache to a larger value, say 2000, in vlc player. You can find the setting in tools/preferences with "all" checked in show settings. Then go to Input/Codecs, where near the bottom of the window it says advanced/file caching. Set it to 2000 and save, then restart VLC player. Voilà, it worked for me. It took me a second to find the show settings at the bottom, and then it took a little while longer to find the file caching, but once I found it, it worked perfectly. You might also want to reset VLC player, just in case you messed it up really bad, and then increase the cache value. Good Luck.